# How to allow RESTful application to use system classes in Caché?

Tags: rest, intersystems-cache

When trying to set "Dispatch Class" for any RESTful application to the class hold in system package, for example, "%WebTerminal.Router", any request to this web-application responds "403 Forbidden".

However, when I rename package to "WebTerminal.Router" (without "%" sign) and set the dispatch class to this class everything works great.

Is there any way to "allow" RESTful applications to use system classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 ways to allow % classes in CSP context:

a) Allow all % classes:

```
Set ^SYS("Security", "CSP", "AllowPercent")=1
```

b) Allow one class for one app:

```
Set ^SYS("Security", "CSP", "AllowClass", application, class)=1
```

c) Allow one class for all apps:

```
Set ^SYS("Security", "CSP", "AllowClass", 0, class)=1
```

Any of the commands must be executed in %SYS namespace.

Comment: Thank you! In my case the perfect solution was `set ^SYS("Security", "CSP", "AllowClass", "/terminal/", "%WebTerminal.Router") = 1` (slash at the end of web app's name is required)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a RESTfull issue, it is for all %-classes. You can read about it in documentation [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCSP_config#GCSP_appaccess). To allow it just do this.

```
zn "%SYS"
Set ^SYS("Security", "CSP", "AllowPrefix", 0, "%WebTerminal") = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Wondering that I missed this moment in documentation.